# Is there a way to add a delay to eclipse tooltips?

Tags: eclipse

I've found [this article](http://eclipseone.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/configure-tooltips-in-eclipse-to-only-popup-on-request/) about using the shift key to make the tooltips popup when you want them to. This works ok, but I was wondering if there is a way to just add a delay to the tooltip. I like the default hover behavior, it's just a bit too eager on the display. I'm using Helios on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excellent question!

There doesn't appear to be a control in Eclipse to do it, but these two blog entries:

- http://untamedmind.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/changing-the-mousehovertime-add-delay-on-the-tooltips-pop-up/
- http://dandar3.blogspot.com/2008/09/tooltip-delay-in-windows.html

both say it can be done in the windows registry.  Caveat: I have not tried this.

Comment: Thanks. Guess I was just googling it wrong. I already had TweakUI installed (from the second link). Never even thought to look there.

Comment: @xecaps12 If you end up trying this, could you please comment your result?

Comment: @xecaps12 thanks.  Now the answer is here to help other stackoverflow users.

Comment: Any user feedback for Eclipse on GNU/Linux?

Comment: 2nd option worked for me, used `MouseHoverTime` of 500 on Windows 8.1. Seems like Eclipse really should have a separate setting for this, though.

Answer (score 0):

*Eclipse tooltip delay is derived from Windows*, so if you change the delay of windows by editing registory it will show delay on eclipse as well.

`In Windows -> Start -> Run -> regedit.exe`

Go to below path in registry.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Mouse/`

Modify value for Key `MouseHoverTime`

`MouseHoverTime : 600`

> NOTE : The value is in miliseconds, for me it was 8 miliseoncds and I
>   changed it to 600 miliseoncds.

**System restart required after changing value in registry**

OR

You can also assign shortcut key to get the tooltop when ever you want. Please refer below link

[Link](http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2010/08/24/configure-tooltips-in-eclipse-to-only-popup-on-request/)

Answer (score -2):

I suggest to turn off hovers by default, and define a customKey in Eclipse->Preferences if necessary.

Comment: your suggestion is not relevant to the question at all