# Is it possible in Eclipse to set longer time to show hints?

Tags: eclipse

I want to know if it's possible to set a longer time to show hints in eclipse?
Eclipse has many hints(tooltips) for suggesting about error corrections or description about classes.
It makes me nervous, when I want to select my code with mouse to copy or doing something else, this ugly hint appears so fast.

Comment: You can force it manually with F2, and it stays open. I don't think is possible to increase the time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to add a delay to eclipse tooltips?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778452/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-delay-to-eclipse-tooltips)

Answer (score 2):

This is what i've found:
[eclipse hint](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_c_editor_con_assist.htm), maybe it can help you.

You can go to the editor preferences:

Window -> Preferences -> "your language" -> Editor -> Content Assist

and choose how many delay you want

Comment: No man, It's not what I want. I want to delay the hint when the mouse stops on a word in my code, for example a class name, appears.