# Change/remove hover delay in Eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, pydev

I'm using Eclipse, and have set up my preferences so that editor hovers only appear when I press `Ctrl` by using the "Combined Hovers Keys Modifier" setting. However, when I Ctrl+Hover an item, I still have to wait for the hover delay.

**Is there any way to remove this delay?**

I'm using multiple Eclipse distributions, all at least Oxygen or newer. This is also for multiple OSes, including Fedora, Ubuntu, and Windows.

I'm looking for answers that *don't* tamper with operating system settings. Solutions like the accepted answer for this [question about adding delay to tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5778452) aren't acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Hovers in Eclipse are implemented by registering an SWT `MouseTrackListener` on the control (GUI element) that wants to react to being hovered over, and showing the hover when `MouseTrackListener.mouseHover()` is invoked.

The [documentation for `MouseTrackListener.mouseHover()`](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fevents%2FMouseTrackListener.html&anchor=mouseHover-org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent-) says:

> Sent when the mouse pointer hovers (that is, stops moving for an
>   (operating system specified) period of time) over a control.

suggesting that there is no cross-platform way to change the delay.

You could consider [filing an SWT issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform&component=SWT) to request adding an option for customizing the delay.